# The Benefits of Knowledge in the Advancement of Humantity

Tags: knowledge

> The more and the more easily messengers reach everywhere here, everywhere there, then the
> more the communication of thoughts is advanced, and no prince, no king will seek to hinder
> this who understands the infinite advantages of the mind-industry, of mind-culture, of the
> reciprocal communication of inventions, thoughts, suggestions, even of mistakes committed
> and weaknesses. Every one of these things benefits human nature, and hence also society; the
> mistake gets discovered, the error gets corrected, thought awakens thought, sensations and
> decisions stimulate and motivate.

Herder, J. (2002). Letters for the Advancement of Humanity (1793–7) [excerpts concerning freedom of thought and expression]. In M. Forster (Ed.), Herder: Philosophical Writings (Cambridge Texts in the History of Philosophy, pp. 370-373). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9781139164634.016

I am currently having a hard time trying to understand the very last line about awakening thoughts I hope someone can explain it to me

Comment: Context: the [French campaigns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon#First_Italian_campaign) in Europe led by Napoleon were a powerful "media" to spread Enlightenment ideas through Europe.

Comment: According to Herder, the communication of ideas, thoughts, discoveries are a powerful force driving "Advancement of Humanity".

Comment: If the yearning for knowledge is suppressed for a long time and the person stops trying, you’ll see this person will be inevitably drowned into the task-oriented Sisyphean depression state...